# Integer variable is zero when is it null in database

Tags: java, jdbc, integer

I have declared variable as

```
private Integer projectId;

   public void setProjectId(Integer projectId) {
    this.projectId= projectId;
}

public Integer getProjectId() {
    return projectId;
}
```

While retrieving values from database, if projectId is null in database table, it is shown as `0` e.g.

```
log.info("?? "+projectList.get(1).getProjectId());
```

the result of the above is `0`.

Why it is shown as `0` although it is null in table and how can I make  this is as `null` when it is `null` in table?

**Edit 1**

```
while (rs.next()) {
projectList.add(mapProjects(resultSet));

}

private static Project mapProjects(ResultSet rs) 
throws SQLException {
return new Project ((rs.getInt("ID")), 
(rs.getInt("PROJECT_ID")),
```

Comment: You have to call wasNull() to see if it was null.

Comment: Are either your getter or setters using primitive variables?

Comment: @ns47731 I have included my getter and setter in question.

Comment: @ns47731, even if the getter/setter used `int` instead of `Integer` you'd just get a NullReferenceException when trying to return it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to handle that case yourself. The [`ResultSet` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt%28int%29) clearly states (emphasis mine):

> `getInt int getInt(int columnIndex)`
>
> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as an int in the
>   Java programming language.
>
> *Parameters:*
>   * columnIndex - the first column is 1, the second is 2, ...
>
> *Returns:*
>   the column value; **if the value
>   is SQL NULL, the value returned is 0**

You have to call [`wasNull()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull%28%29) after reading a column value and set your field to `null` if that was the case. So something like the following:

```
Integer projectId = rs.getInt("PROJECT_ID");
if (rs.wasNull()) projectId = null;
return new Project (rs.getInt("ID"), projectId), ...);
```

For sanity reasons it's probably nicer if you move that code into a new method:

```
/**
 * Retrieves the value from the designated column as an {@link Integer}
 * object.
 * 
 * @param rs
 *            The ResultSet to read from.
 * @param columnName
 *            The column name to read.
 * @return {@code null} if the column value was SQL NULL; its value as an
 *         integer otherwise.
 */
public static Integer getInteger(ResultSet rs, String columnName) {
    int v = rs.getInt(columnName);
    return rs.wasNull() ? null : v;
}
```

Comment: Joey I have included my retrieving database code snippet in question, how can I check `wasNull`?

Comment: It's a bit annoying because you *first* have to retrieve the value and *then* check for `NULL` (which makes a conditional operator useless here). I added some code.

Comment: Ah I see, so what is the best approach and practice?

Comment: Well, as a developer you know that abstraction can be a powerful tool in reducing mindless chores to calling aptly-named methods ;-)